# Collect data from user during file upload.

Tags: 2013, data

I want to setup my SharePoint in way that when I upload file in Document Library it will be automatic create line in SharePoint List with information from user. Should work in this way:

1. User Upload file in Document Library View.
2. When document are uploading or just after finish upload, should popup some kind of window with fields to fill and button "done".
3. After click "Done", should be crated new line in List and data from previously filled fields should be in appropriate columns.

First part of these I already done, which is when I upload file, SharePoint automatically creating new line in my List. But for now I setup data manually in Workflow "Create item" action. I can't figure out how to collect data from user.

Thanks for help.

Tobiasz

Answer (score 1):

No workflow needed, just add a column to the library and mark it as required.